# nodeJS connection with Google API

Tags: google-hangouts

I am trying to connect hangouts chat API with NodeJS but did not find any documentation related to Oauth in NodeJS, without which I can not connect to APIs. There is a code in Python but is there any thing in Node so that we can do the API call from front end it self.

Answer (score 0):

### The Oauth flow is the same for all Google APIs

- If there is a quickstart for a specific API in a specific language missing, you can use one from another API.
- For example, there is a [Node.js quickstart for the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs)
- You can take it as a base and have to modify only 2 things:

1. Modify

   `const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];`

   by specifying the scopes you are going to use, for example

   `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat`
2. For building the service, modify

   `const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});`

   to

   `const chat = google.chat({version: 'v1', auth});`

- Mind that depending on the application, you might need to use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/service-accounts)
- The documentaiton about implementing a service account in node.js can be found  [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)